# ¿Cómo definir un Static Dictionary con elementos initializados en C#?

Tags: c#

Buen día hermanos de SOes, tengo esta situación:

Necesito un diccionario con datos previamente definidos, se supone que este diccionario es de solo lectura por lo que la pregunta del millón es:

> ¿Cómo puedo definir un diccionario estático con elementos inicializados?

De esta manera cuando tenga que trabajar alguna `clave`, el `valor` será obtenido del diccionario.

Comment: Define "es de solo lectura". Una cosa es que una vez inicializado el diccionario, no puedes darle "new" una segunda vez (usando la palabra reservada "readonly") y otra es que una vez inicializado no puedas agregar elementos.

Comment: Claro mi estimado, en el escenario donde estoy, el "es solo de lectura" = Una instancia (por lo de static) + Sin agregar elementos. Esta es una pregunta-respuesta porque no he encontrado alguna pregunta similar en SOes y como programador en C#, vi que era necesario compartir contenido así :)

Comment: Necesitas usar un diccionario de solo lectura: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlydictionary-2.values?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si los datos de ese diccionario son solo de lectura y es un diccionario para toda la clase, hazlo `static` y del tipo `readonly`

```
public class ClaseDeEjemplo {

    public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> ejemploDiccionario = new Dictionary<string, string>() {           
        {"Clave1", "Valor1"},
        {"Clave2", "Valor2"},
        {"Clave3", "Valor3"}
    };

}
```

Y la utilizas de la siguiente manera:

```
var ValorDependiendoDeLaClave = ejemploDiccionario[VariableDeNombreDeAlgunaClave];
```

Es decir, si en `VariableDeNombreDeAlgunaClave` contiene un string llamado `Clave1` , el valor será `Valor1`.

Answer (score 1):

En vez de un Dictionary usas un ReadOnlyDictionary:

```
readonly static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> dictionary;

static TheClass() // TheClass es el nombre de la clase que contendrá el diccionario estático
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>{
        ["1"] = 1,
        ["2"] = 2,
        ["3"] = 3
    };

    dictionary = new ReadOnlyDictionary<stringm, int>(dict);
}
```

O si usas una versión de Visual Studio menor a la 2015:

```
readonly static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> dictionary;

static TheClass() // TheClass es el nombre de la clase que contendrá el diccionario estático
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>{
        { "1", 1 },
        { "2", 2 },
        { "3", 3 }
    };

    dictionary = new ReadOnlyDictionary<stringm, int>(dict);
}
```

Aunque yo prefiero la primera opción, queda mas claro que son datos de un diccionario.